# Deprecated Properties in Gradle 6.1.1

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

After I upgraded Gradle From 5.1.1 to 6.1.1 and flutter to 2.0.2
there are a lot of errors and deprecated properties in Gradle

Like

```
Property 'assets' is not annotated with an input or output annotation. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0.
```

```
Property 'assetsDirectory' is not annotated with an input or output annotation. This behaviour has been deprecated 
and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0.
```

and other errors, How can I fix all of it once ?
or how find the deprecated property and update it?